# ALERT - ONE OF YOUR APPS NEEDS ATTENTION

Tags: google-play

I updated an old app yesterday , however I didn't change anything, only I added a push notification. 
but seems the new policy and guidelines are against my app or my app it is.

I got the following warning 
***"ALERT - ONE OF YOUR APPS NEEDS ATTENTION
One or more of your apps were rejected for violation of Google Play policies. Once you address the issues you can resubmit your apps."***

, I'm worry about the violation I guess I found it but how can I know it's the only one and if I fix it and resubmit my app will not get suspended ?

Is there any way/tool to check app violations before submitting it to play store ? cause as you know things for developers seems legal but for google is extremely violated .. who knows how google thinks !

Answer (score 1):

Before re-submitting the app, make sure that you understand and follow the [Google Play Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html) that you accepted when registering. Google Play actively enforces the policies and any violations can lead to suspension of your apps or, for repeated violations, termination of your developer account. You can find the official Google Play Launch Checklist to see if you did all recommended steps: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html.

References:

- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4430948
- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?rd=1#topic=2364761

Comment: If you strongly believe your app was rejected or removed in error, feel free to file an appeal. Google will approve or reinstate your app if they find that the initial decision was made in error. You can appeal your app’s current status by submitting an appeal request: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appappeals.